# Flow HTTP Request for SharePoint to invite external guest user

Tags: flow

I've been playing with HTTP Request for SharePoint, trying to invite an external guest user to the site through Flow.

I can successfully generate a bearer token, am assuming I need it for the function shown below, but thats as far as I get.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/invitation_post

[image]

Comment: If you can successfully post the same request with javascript, why would it not work in flow? https://medium.com/southworks/adding-a-guest-to-an-office-365-sharepoint-site-with-javascript-fa7604ad8678

Comment: any solution you found?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for:  https://www.schaeflein.net/connecting-the-clouds-developer/